# Lookup values in DAX from another table without relation (multiple conditions)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two tables like this.

Table A

| Duration | Currency | Type | Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | USD | Annual | 0.34 |
| 2 | EUR | Period | 0.41 |

Table B

| Duration | Currency | Type | Product | Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | USD | Annual | Medelli |  |
| 2 | EUR | Period | Longoka |  |

I need to bring the "Rate" in Table A to Table B by the first three column conditions (Duration, Currency, and Type). Which formula do I need to use in the New Column? Thanks beforehand

P.S - I need the unique value of rate, not the sum. And these two tables have no relation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a calculated column (not a measure) in Table B:

```
Rate =
LOOKUPVALUE (
    'Table A'[Rate],
    'Table A'[Duration], 'Table B'[Duration],
    'Table A'[Currency], 'Table B'[Currency],
    'Table A'[Type], 'Table B'[Type]
)
```